# URL slash '/' get double encoded. Changed to %252F instead of %2F in Android Api Retrofit Kotlin

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

I'm getting an Api response as this

X-Amz-Credential=0XCA1HQW6NU67Z1FP3U1%2F20221011%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request

But when I send this value as query parameters in the next Api, It is automatically converted into

X-Amz-Credential=0XCA1HQW6NU67Z1FP3U1%252F20221011%252Fus-east-1%252Fs3%252Faws4_request

wherever there is %2F it is converted into %252F, So the Api is failing as 400 Bad request.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `encoded` property of retrofit's `@Query` annotation to mark the value as already encoded, preventing it from being URL
encoded again.

For example:

```
@Query(value = "credential", encoded = true) credential: String
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix it by first decoding the original response and then sending it as a query param to next request. You can use one of the below methods for decoding:

```kotlin
import android.net.Uri

Uri.decode(response)
```

OR

```kotlin
import java.net.URLDecoder

URLDecoder.decode(response, "utf-8")
```

For `response = 0XCA1HQW6NU67Z1FP3U1%2F20221011%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request`,
the decoded response will be `0XCA1HQW6NU67Z1FP3U1/20221011/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request`